# How to fix Left Join SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have two following tables. 
Table A:

```
 Email            Phone
 A@gmail.com      1234
 B@gmail.com      2345
 C@gmail.com      4567
 D@gmail.com      5432
 E@gmail.com      4568
```

Table B:

```
 Email            LinkName
 A@gmail.com      X
 B@gmail.com      Y
 C@gmail.com      
 D@gmail.com      X
 B@gmail.com      X
```

Desired Output:

```
 Email           LinkName
 C@gmail.com     
 E@gmail.com
```

Following is the query which I tried. Please let me know is it correct:

```
   Select Email from Table A
     Left join  Table B
     on A.Email = B.Email
     where C.LinkName is null
```

Answer (score 1):

No, `C.LinkName` you don't have C table

```
SELECT
A.Email
FROM TABLE A
LEFT JOIN TABLE B
     ON A.Email = B.Email
     WHERE B.LinkName IS NULL
```

This one is the right one, `LinkName` is B column so you have to modify it in WHERE statement

If you want `LinkName` column (as in your desired output) you should add `B.LinkName` in your SELECT, but it will be filled with NULL values only

Comment: Thank You, Pave. I had included. I forgot to type here. Thank you